# NSPredicate Ignore Numbers In String [pinyin]

Tags: ios, nsstring, numbers, nspredicate

I've looked around a lot but have been unable to find an answer for this one...

I have a class in my app that contains *Chinese Pinyin* pronunciation set up as
pronunciation# [space] pronunciation#
for instance *你好*[hello] would be 
*ni3 hao3*

so my question is how can I get `NSPredicate` to ignore the numbers in the string/class during a search?

ideally I would be able to search: 
"*nihao*" 
"*ni hao*" 
etc

and still end up with the same result (*你好 ni3 hao3*)

I've  tried out a few *LIKE* instances but have failed miserably every time...

Thanks

here's my array, as per request:

```
     -(NSMutableArray *) wordList{
    cdh = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cdh.sqlite"];
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        }


        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM MAIN";
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }else{

            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                Words * word = [[Words alloc] init];
                word.head = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,0)];
                word.pro = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
                word.def = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
                [cdh addObject:word];
            }
        }
         sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return cdh;

    }
}
```

Words.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface Words : NSObject {
NSString *head;
NSString *pro;
NSString *def;
}

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *head;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *pro;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *def;

@end
```

Words.m

```
#import "Words.h"

@implementation Words

@synthesize head;
@synthesize pro;
@synthesize def;

- (NSString *)searchableStringValue {
NSCharacterSet *invalidSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[]0123456789 "] invertedSet];
NSString *searchString = [[pro componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return searchString;
}

@end
```

TestViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "Words.h"

    @interface TestViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *cdh;
    sqlite3 * db;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *cdh;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *myData;

-(NSMutableArray *) wordList;

@end
```

TestViewController.m (inc. predicate)

```
    - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
    {
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(head beginswith[c] %@) OR (searchableStringValue beginswith[c] %@)", searchText, searchText];
        searchResults = [cdh filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    }

    -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
    {
        [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                                   scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                          objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                         selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

        return YES;
    }
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];
    } else {
    return [self.cdh count];
}
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
//    int rowCount = indexPath.row;

//    Words *word = [self.cdh objectAtIndex:rowCount];
//    cell.textLabel.text = word.head;
 //   cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", word.pro, word.def];

    // Configure the cell...
    Words *word = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        word = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        word = [cdh objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = word.head;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", word.pro, word.def];
    return cell;
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowWordDetails"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
    Words *word = nil;

    if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        word = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        word = [cdh objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    DetailsViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.word = word;
}
}
```

Comment: How are your strings stored? In a dictionary / custom object / Core Data?

Comment: Not sure really to be honest, kind of new to all of this...the strings are loaded from a sqlite database [not sure if this is what you are asking] and then saved in an Array

Comment: Can you log a sample array and add to the question then please (perhaps with a little code showing what you did to generate the log).

Comment: sorry to be a total retard but I'm not really sure what you mean by asking me to log a sample array...

Comment: Your strings are in an array you say - log the contents of the array (so we can see if / check that it is just strings, or some container objects). Sample refers to a relatively small subset of whatever you have in your database.

Comment: i edited my orignal comment -- i hope that's what you were asking for

Comment: For "ni hao", you could look for something like "ni[0-9] hao[0-9]", using a stringWithFormat to decompose each one with space. But finding "nihao" from "ni3 hao3", you'll have to change all your find, erase numbers and spaces, at least, that's a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings are contained in a `Words` class. This gives you a perfect opportunity to create additional methods to help out with processing the strings it holds (i.e. you don't need to try doing everything in the predicate).

For instance, consider adding a method which returns:

```
- (NSString *)searchableStringValue
```

this method would take the string that you are currently trying to search and mutate it to remove the brackets, numbers, spaces. This can most easily be achieved with:

```
NSCharacterSet *invalidSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[]0123456789 "] invertedSet];
NSString *searchString = [[##XXX## componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

where ##XXX## is the string that you are currently trying to search.

Now, your predicate should use `searchableStringValue`, instead of the string that you are currently trying to search.

Comment: how to reference word.pro in the ##XXX## part?
i tried word.pro and self.word.pro but doesn't seem to connect...

Comment: `self.pro` because this is inside the `Words` class and `word` is a different reference to the instance...

Comment: p.s. Welcome to stack overflow. Please remember to up-vote answers that help and tick answers that solve your problem ;-)

Comment: thank you so much for all your help, I feel like rainman in a candyshop ;) 
I'm getting an error that says 'pro' is not an object typed found on my controller...any ideas?

Comment: Then you haven't added the code to the `Words` class. `searchableStringValue` is added to `Words` class and used in the predicate.

Comment: so in my words.m class i added the following:


`- (NSString *)searchableStringValue {
NSCharacterSet *invalidSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[]0123456789 "] invertedSet];
NSString *searchString = [[pro componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return searchString;
}`


but I'm getting a crash on search now -- is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: my predicate looks like this
`- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(head beginswith[c] %@) OR (searchableStringValue beginswith[cd] %@)", searchText, searchText];
    searchResults = [cdh filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}`

Comment: What is the exception name and message?

Comment: output only says:
(lldb)

breakpoint points to the } after:
return searchString; 

just reads: thread 1; breakpoint 4.1;

Comment: Try pressing continue button to get more details

Comment: when I press continue I just get this:
`self Words * 0xa21b810 0x0a21b810
NSObject NSObject  
head __NSCFString * @"巴" 0x0a22f770
pro __NSCFString * @"ba1" 0x0a22f780
def __NSCFString * @"[pa⁵⁵] ①粘" 0x0a22dc30
searchString __NSCFString * @"1" 0x0898e150
NSObject NSObject  
isa Class __NSCFString 0x0196833c
invalidSet __NSCFCharacterSet * 0x8983330 0x08983330
NSObject NSObject  
isa Class __NSCFCharacterSet 0x01968404
pro __NSCFString * @"ba1" 0x0a22f780
NSObject NSObject  
isa Class __NSCFString 0x0196833c`
seems to be going one-by-one through the database..and getting stuck at the end of each

Comment: Is that in the console?

Comment: yeah, not in output but in the console

Comment: Try removing `(head beginswith[c] %@) OR ` from the predicate if you can't find the exception information. And log the `searchableStringValue ` to check what it is too.

Comment: Update the question with formatted code showing the `Words` class content, where you're running the predicate, a log of what you're running it on. If you can't find exception details then I'm wild guessing without real code to look at...

Comment: Where is `searchResults` used? Really need to know the scope of the exception, name, message. If you don't use the predicate and just set `searchResults = cdh` do you get an exception? Is the exception only when you search (or do what)?

Comment: before adding the "searchableStringValue" string I was getting, somewhat, working search results for both "head" and "pro" in my app - the results were very "stiff" but it was working so it must be something to do with my implementation of the new code

Comment: apparently my reputation is too low to post messages in chat

Comment: even when invited? shame. Anyway - tell me about the exception, when is it thrown?

Comment: thrown on search, the app loads fine -- table loads fine -- search opens okay and then typing a letter crashes the whole thing

Comment: Add 2 logs in `searchableStringValue`. I before anything else is done with `pro`, 1 with the `searchString` to be returned.

Comment: they're returning the same thing:
pro: ba1
searchableStringValue: ba1

Comment: I removed the brackets [,] out of the expression and the app isn't crashing anymore -- but search results are showing up blank..

Comment: actually it's doing the opposite of what I wanted -- it's removing everything BUT numbers if i search "1" or whatever I start to get results...getting there...

Comment: removed inverted set:
this is the code that I finally got working:
`- (NSString *)searchableStringValue {
    NSCharacterSet *invalidSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234 "];
    NSString *searchString = [[pro componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return searchString;
}`
finally, thank you so much for all your help again!

Comment: post a comment over here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844888/nspredicate-character-and-or-letter-substitutions -- I'll give you the credit for it aswell